# How can I use SFINAE to disable a function inside a class based on template type

Tags: c++, sfinae

I have a template class

```cpp
template<typename TLoader, typename TCreator>
class ManagerGroup {
public:
  uint32_t loadFromPath(const Path &path) {
    return mLoader.load(path);
  }

  void createFile(uint32_t handle) {
    return mCreator.create(handle);
  }

private:
  TLoader mLoader;
  TCreator mCreator;
};
```

For the `loadFromPath` and `createFile` functions, I want to disable them if the provided typename is `std::nullptr_t`; so, I can do something like this:

```cpp
ManagerGroup<FontLoader, std::nullptr_t> fontManager;

// No issues
fontManager.loadFromPath("/test");

// Compilation error
fontManager.createFile(10);

ManagerGroup<std::nullptr_t, MeshCreator> meshManager;

// NO issues
meshManager.createFile(20);

// Throws error
meshManager.loadFromFile("/test");
```

Is this possible with SFINAE?

I tried the following but could not get it working (based on example #5 in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if):

```cpp
template<typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::same<TCreator, std::nullptr_t>::value>>
void createFile(uint32_t handle) {
  return mCreator.create(handle);
}
```

Comment: This has become much simpler with C++20 if you can use it. Or which C++ version do you support?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am in c++17 still but my understanding is that concepts is just fancy syntax around SFINAE.

Comment: `std::enable_if` is also pretty potent if you can't go `concepts` Edit: Ok, I see you tried that ...

Comment: No, in this case `requires` clauses allow for disabling non-template member functions, which beforehand wasn't simply possible with SFINAE but required relatively complex inheritance schemes. (But that is not an issue here since you don't seem to care about whether or not the member function is a template.)

Comment: Could `static_assert`s be better?

Comment: Static assert does not remove the function. My problem is that if I provide nullptr_t to a template parameter, I can't call any function inside that class.

Comment: @Gasim You don't need to remove functions for that. As long as you are not using explicit instantiation, the member function bodies are going to be instantiated only when you try to call them (or otherwise odr-use them). There is no problem with `return mLoader.load(path);` even if `mLoader` is a `nullptr_t` as long as you do not try to call `loadFromPath` (which would then fail with an error message anyway). The snippet you are showing with the expected behavior already applies to the original code. The error message is only going to be less readable.

Comment: I just realized that my function's argument was based on a structure that is in the class, which was causing the issue when I was not even calling the function. I think I can try to use static assert as well here now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for SFINAE to work you need to use a parameter that is being deduced.  In your case `TCreator` is already known so you can't use it.  You can instead get around the problem by adding your own parameter and defaulting it to `TCreator` like

```
template<typename T = TCreator,
         std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<T, std::nullptr_t>, bool> = true>
void createFile(uint32_t handle) {
  return mCreator.create(handle);
}
```

Comment: Maybe also a `std::is_same_v<T, TCreator>` in there to prevent the instantiation of `createFile` with non-default values for the template type